# Schema Locks Grayed Out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, schema-locks

Schema locks are not showing up in the Oracle Instance when viewed using ArcCatalog. Data is being using in different applications but for some reason I'm not able to view the locks as the data owner/geodatabase administrator on Oracle instance.

Does it need any specific permissions assigned on Oracle for GDB Admin to access the locks?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because of other items being grayed out, I assume that you are not connected as the sde user or an administrator or owner to that database.

From [ArcGIS Managing Schema Locks Help Page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/manage-geodatabase-locks.htm), it appears that locks are available to the sde user (and my guess would be anyone else that is listed as an 'owner' to that database):

> Clicking the Refresh button updates the list with the most current connection details.
>
> Start ArcMap or ArcCatalog and connect to the geodatabase as the sde
> user. Right-click the database connection in the Catalog tree, point
> to Administration, click Administer Geodatabase, then click the Locks
> tab. The Locks list opens, and you can see all locks on all objects in
> the geodatabase.
>
> Contact the user who holds the lock that needs to be released and ask
> him or her finish the transaction and disconnect from the geodatabase.
> If the person is gone for the day and the lock needs to be released
> immediately, you can disconnect the user.
>
> ***Caution:*** Use caution when
> disconnecting users. Esri recommends that you avoid disconnecting
> active sessions, especially if the connected user is in the process of
> editing. You should only disconnect users to drop locks if a session
> was left open even when not being used (for example, over the
> weekend), if a session is orphaned and locking an object, or if a
> deadlock situation occurs.
>
> If necessary, right-click the lock and click Disconnect User. The sde
> user must be a super user to disconnect users.

Comment: Hi @mary beth, Thanks for responding on the issue. I've connected to the DB as Data Owner. For some reason it doesn't show the locks for SDE and DataOwner users. Do you think of any permission issues ?